# I don't receive an email from firebase to reset the password in react native and expo please

Tags: reactjs, react-native

```
const ForgotPassword = ({ navigation }) => {

  const [email, setEmail] = React.useState("")
  const [emailError, setEmailError] = React.useState("")
  const [focus, setFocus] = React.useState(false)


  function isEnableSendEmail() {
    return email !== "" && emailError == ""
  }

  const RestPassword = () => {
    auth
      .sendPasswordResetEmail(email)
      .then(() => {
        Alert.alert("Password reset email has been sent")
      }, (error) => {
        Alert.alert(error.message)
      }
      )

  }


  return (
    <AuthLayout
      title='Password Recovery'
      subtitle='Please Enter Your Email Address to Recover
   Your password'
      titleStyle={{
        marginTop: SIZES.padding * 2
      }}
    >
      {/*Form Input*/}
      <View
        style={{
          flex: 1,
          marginTop: SIZES.padding
        }}
      >
        <FormInput
          label='Email'
          keyboardType='email-address'
          autoCompleteType='email'
          onChange={(value) => {
            //validate email
            utils.validateEmail(value, setEmailError)
            setEmail(value)
          }}

          errorMsg={emailError}
          appendComponent={
            <View
              style={{
                justifyContent: 'center'
              }}
            >
              <Image
                source={email == "" || (email != "" &&
                  emailError == "") ? icons.correct : icons.cancel}
                style={{
                  height: 20,
                  width: 20,
                  tintColor: email == "" ?
                    COLORS.gray : (email != "" &&
                      emailError == "") ? COLORS.green
                      : COLORS.red
                }}
              />


            </View>
          }
        />
      </View>

      {/*Button*/}

      <AppButton
        label='Send Email'
        disabled={isEnableSendEmail() ? false : true}
        buttonStyle={{
          height: 50,
          marginTop: SIZES.padding,
          borderRadius: SIZES.radius,
          backgroundColor: isEnableSendEmail() ?
            COLORS.primary : COLORS.secondary,
          alignItems: 'center'
        }}

        onPress={RestPassword}


      />
    </AuthLayout>
  )
}
```

When I type my email to reset the password and I go to check my Gmail inbox I don't receive an email coming from the firebase admin please do help me and thank you in advance.

Comment: Have a look at the accepted answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70642016/firebase-sendpasswordresetemail-not-working-in-react

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Firebase sendPasswordResetEmail not working in React](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70642016/firebase-sendpasswordresetemail-not-working-in-react)